# Combine two queries to get the data in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT 
    tblEmployeeMaster.TeamName, SUM(tblData.Quantity) AS 'TotalQuantity'
FROM 
    tblData 
INNER JOIN
    tblEmployeeMaster ON tblData.EntryByHQCode = tblEmployeeMaster.E_HQCode 
INNER JOIN
    tblPhotos ON tblEmployeeMaster.TeamNo = tblPhotos.TeamNo
WHERE
    IsPSR = 'Y'
GROUP BY 
    tblPhotos.TeamSort, tblPhotos.TeamNo, tblPhotos.Data, 
    tblEmployeeMaster.TeamName
ORDER BY
    tblPhotos.TeamSort DESC, TotalQuantity DESC
```

This returns

[image]

Using this statement

```
select TeamName, count(TeamName) AS 'Head Count' 
from dbo.tblEmployeeMaster
where IsPSR = 'Y'
group by teamname
```

Which returns

[image]

I would like to combine these 2 queries in 1 to get the below result.

[image]

Tried union / union all but no success :(

Any help will be very much helpful.

Comment: Why are you grouping by all those other columns in  your initial query, when none of them appear in your `SELECT`?

Comment: Does your first query really return the specified result? I'd expect an exception...

Comment: @jarlh What is wrong with the first query?

Comment: @DavidG, the GROUP BY clause doesn't match the SELECT list, and I find it hard to believe it returns the specified result. (However, SQL Server may oddly enough accept a string literal as column alias, instead of an identifier - so perhaps it doesn't raise an error?)

Comment: @jarlh You don't need to SELECT everything from the GROUP BY, and a string alias works fine.

Comment: @DavidG, I know, but if you don't, the result usually contains duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh You said it would throw an error

Comment: @DavidG, I know, I forgot about the MS SQL Server special for string literal as column alias. (_I'd expect an exception_...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT tblEmployeeMaster.TeamName, SUM(tblData.Quantity) AS 'TotalQuantity', 
        MAX(HEAD_COUNT) AS HEAD_COUNT, -- USE THIS VALUE FROM SUB-QUERY
        CASE WHEN MAX(HEAD_COUNT) <> 0 
             THEN SUM(tblData.Quantity)/MAX(HEAD_COUNT) 
        END AS PER_MAN_CONTRIBUTION -- column asked in comment
  FROM tblData INNER JOIN
  tblEmployeeMaster ON tblData.EntryByHQCode = tblEmployeeMaster.E_HQCode INNER JOIN
  tblPhotos ON tblEmployeeMaster.TeamNo = tblPhotos.TeamNo
  -- FOLLOWING SUB-QUERY CAN BE USED
  LEFT JOIN (select TeamName, count(TeamName) AS HEAD_COUNT 
                from dbo.tblEmployeeMaster
               where IsPSR = 'Y' group by teamname) AS HC  
         ON HC.TeamName = tblEmployeeMaster.TeamName
  where IsPSR = 'Y'
  GROUP BY tblPhotos.TeamSort, tblPhotos.TeamNo, tblPhotos.Data,tblEmployeeMaster.TeamName
  order by tblPhotos.TeamSort desc, TotalQuantity desc
```

Comment: Classic :) :)  Could you please add another column which divides TotalQuantity / Head Count and Show the Per Man Contribution?

Comment: Updated the answer. Refer -- column asked in comment -- in code

Comment: You are awesome :) :) :) Thank you So Muchhhhh..... Digging this for 3 hours and you did it in a minute :)